# Setting multiple properties of a UIView (or object) with less semi boilerplate - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I'm setting properties of a `UIStackView`. I would do it like this:

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.distribution = .fill
stackView.alignment = .fill
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.spacing = 12
```

The effects of my Carpal tunnel syndrome worsen each time I write `stackView`. I could make an extension which takes these properties, but that's pretty hard to do for a lot of the views, and you can't put all the properties in some extension, it sucks. I have seen sth like this thing I will be putting below in some other languages, and I was wondering if our beloved Swift offers any. I searched but didn't find anything. Any thoughts?:

```
let stackView = UIStackView() {
    distribution = .fill
    alignment = .fill
    axis = .vertical
    spacing = 12
 }
```

P.S: I can do something like this (and of course make it generic), but the extra $0 still bugs me.

```
extension UIStackView {
    convenience init(quickSetProperties: (UIStackView) -> Void) {
        quickSetProperties(self)
    }
}

let stackView = UIStackView() {
    $0.distribution = .fill
    $0.distribution = .fill
    $0.alignment = .fill
    $0.axis = .vertical
    $0.spacing = 12
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately **Swift** closures do not support this. In your case, you either have to use `$0` or explicitly define a variable `{ stackView in ... }` in a closure to modify an underlying view.

Answer (score 1):

As Tomas already said ***Swift** closures do not support this*.

A different approach is a class method with default values for example

```
extension UIStackView {
    static func createCustom(distribution : UIStackView.Distribution = .fill,
                             alignment : UIStackView.Alignment = .fill,
                             axis : NSLayoutConstraint.Axis = .vertical,
                             spacing : CGFloat = 12.0) -> UIStackView {
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.distribution = distribution
        stackView.alignment = alignment
        stackView.axis = axis
        stackView.spacing = spacing
        return stackView
    }
}
```

So to create a new stackview with default values but with a different `axis` just write

```
let s = UIStackView.createCustom(axis: .horizontal)
```